# org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot
>   be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

```
public void csvFileUpload(Object obj,List<String> errorList, List<Employee> empErrorList,
        ServiceContext context,List<Employee> empSuccessList) throws IOException, SystemException{

    String[] nextLine;
    StringBuffer errorLine = new StringBuffer("");
    boolean errorFlag = false;


    // class cast exception here :
    MultipartFile multiFile = (MultipartFile) obj;


    // a lot of irrelevant code deleted. Check
    // the question's history if you want to see it all
}}
```

Why do I get this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object cannot be typecast to a legitimate superclass, you definitely have those classes duplicated on the classpath. The error message just prints the name, but there are actually two classes with the same name. Investigate on your classpath for two libraries that contain the same classes - most likely `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`.

Check your webapplication as well as the global (application server's) classpath. There must be only one of these classes ever.

Comment: yes the problem was on duplicated on the classpath,there are two classes